# How often do pirates need to eat in real time?

Tags: pixel-piracy

I'd like to leave pixel piracy running for a period of time unattended, and to do this I need to know how much food I need to have placed per pirate.

Answer (score 1):

Pirates eat when their hunger reaches %70 so you would need a lot of large food sources like meat sour krout and sea biscuits meat is preferable seeing as it has 7 serving while sourkrout and sea biscuits have 4